# Pegar o ID da última linha inserida no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um projeto que está na seguinte forma:

Primeiro a pessoa irá fazer o upload da foto dela no bd (Tabela: cadastrado, campo: foto)
Porém nesta tabela tem outros campos, para isso criei um formulário que irá alterar a ultima linha cadastrada e acrescentar os outros campos (nome, telefone, email etc) mantendo a foto.

O problema é:  `UPDATE cadastro SET nome = $nome WHERE id = **PROBLEMA**;`

Preciso que o ID seja o ultimo que gravei a foto, mas não sei como faço para pega-lo.

**Para melhor interpretar minha dúvida**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a tabela, e os campos dela Mysql. Já gravei a foto como podem ver.
Agora no formulário quero dar um UPDATE para acrescentar as informações restantes naquela linha ali (id = 20) ex.

**CÓDIGO PARA INSERT DA IMAGEM:**

```
function saveimagem($name, $image)
    {

        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
        mysqli_select_db($conexao, "teste");
        $sql = "insert into cadastro (foto)  values ('$image')";
        if($sql){
        print "ID: ". mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
        }
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        if($result)
        {
            echo "<br/>Foi feito o upload";
        }else
        {
            echo "<br/>Não foi feito o upload";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual api esta usando para conectar com o banco de dados?

Comment: @rray Não, estou fazendo tudo

Comment: Se tiver algum código coloque na pergunta :)

Comment: É so jogar o `mysqli_insert_id()` dentro do `if($result)`

Comment: Uffa. deu certo muito obrigado. Preciso fazer algo agora? Fechar a pergunta?

Comment: Marca a resposta do augusto como aceita, [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo existe uma função chamada `mysqli_insert_id()`, ela captura a `id` gerada automaticamente na última consulta em que se usou o `ÌNSERT` ou `UPDATE`.

Usando o estilo Orientado:

```
$conexao = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");
$stmt = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2) VALUES (1, 'Nome')");
if($stmt){
print "ID: ". $conexao->insert_id;
}
```

Usando o estilo Procedual:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");
$stmt = mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2) VALUES (1, 'Nome')");
if($stmt){
print "ID: ". mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
}
```

[MySQLi Insert ID - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: Obrigado cara, em cima do que você colocou consegui fazer :DD

Comment: Imagina... Estamos ae....