# Utilizar ID gerado de um FORM em outro e fazer UPDATE na bd

Tags: php, mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gravei está imagem no banco de dados me gerou o **ID:20.**

**Formulário para gravar : INICIAL.PHP (Código para gravar imagem)**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="image" /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="sumit" />
    </form>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['sumit']))
    {
        if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])== FALSE)
        {
            echo "Selecione uma imagem.";
        }
        else
        {
            $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image = file_get_contents($image);
            $image = base64_encode($image);
            saveimagem($name, $image);
        }
    }
    mostrarimagem();
    function saveimagem($name, $image)
    {

        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
        mysqli_select_db($conexao, "teste");
        $sql = "insert into cadastro (foto)  values ('$image')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        if($result)
        {
            echo "<br/>Foi feito o upload" ;
            $id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
            echo $id;
        }else
        {
            echo "<br/>Não foi feito o upload";
        }
    }
    function mostrarimagem()
    {
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
        mysqli_select_db($conexao, "teste");
        $sql = "select * from cadastro";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[11].'">';
        }
        mysqli_close($conexao);
    }

    ?>
</body>
```

Onde tem o `$id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);` é a variável que armazenou o ultimo registro no banco de dados. Preciso utilizar ela para no update em outro formulário.

**GRAVAR.PHP**

```
<?php
//Irá receber os valores enviados e guardar no banco de dados

<?php
//Irá receber os valores enviados e guardar no banco de dados
if($_POST['enviar']){
    include 'inicial.php';
    $nome = $_POST['NomeAluno'];
    $dataNasc = $_POST['DataNasc'];
    $sexo = $_POST['Sexo'];
    $numcel = $_POST['Celular'];
    $numtel = $_POST['Telefone'];
    $endereco = $_POST['Endereco'];
    $numres = $_POST['NumResid'];
    $uf = $_POST['UF'];
    $rg = $_POST['RG'];
    $prontuario = $_POST['Prontuario'];
    $datavalidade = $_POST['DataValidade'];
    $curso = $_POST['Curso'];
    $semestre = $_POST['Semestre'];
    $periodo = $_POST['Periodo'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $senha = $_POST['Senha'];

    //"$sql = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM cadastro";

    // Insere os dados no banco
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE cadastro set
                                        nome_aluno = ':$nome',
                                        data_nascimento = ':$dataNasc',
                                        sexo = ':$sexo', 
                                        celular = ':$numcel',
                                        telefone = ':$numtel',
                                        endereco = ':$endereco',
                                        numero = ':$numres',
                                        uf = ':$uf',
                                        rg = ':$rg',
                                        prontuario = ':$prontuario',
                                        data_validade = ':$datavalidade',
                                        curso = ':$curso',
                                        semestre = ':$semestre',
                                        periodo = ':$periodo',
                                        email = ':$email',
                                        senha = ':$senha'
                                  where id = '$id'");

    // Se os dados forem inseridos com sucesso
    if ($sql){
        echo "Você foi cadastrado com sucesso.";
    }
}
?>
```

Não consigo fazer o UPDATE da tabela com os outros valores, sem mexer na foto que já foi gravada. E utilizando a variável $id, até coloquei o `include 'inicial.php';`.

Não sei se é meu SQL de Update que está errado, mas quando clico no botão salvar aparece este erro: `P Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\wamp\www\ifsp\gravar.php on line 45`

Comment: Aqueles `:` na frente das variáveis é o que?

Comment: Não sei porque coloquei, mas não alterou nada, estava sem na verdade

Comment: Onde vc faz a chamada de `saveimage()`? falta retornar o `$id` nessa função ;). tira esses `:` de tudo.

Comment: Só coloquei o include inicial.php, com ele não vai tudo que está na página? *Tirei já*

Comment: Sim, mas precisa chamar `saveimage()` passandos os valores e coloque no final da função `return $id;`

Comment: Quais valores? Assim: ` include 'inicial.php'
saveimagem($id){
  return $id
 }`     . Da erro ainda `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\ifsp\gravar.php on line 22`, uma coisa que notei também, que quando clico em salvar no formulário ele redireciona eu para a página `inicial.php`, só por causa do include

Comment: em inicial.php tem mais código além da função?

Comment: Tem, vou colocar ele inteiro lá em cima

Comment: Cara, você tem que ver se os outros campos aceitam nulo, pois pelo que percebi você adiciona a foto primeiro e depois vc quer pegar o id gerado para atualizar os dados né, tem que ver tbm se o id é gerado automaticamente.

Comment: Sim o ID é auto_increment e quando a foto é gravada os campos estão para aceitar nulo. :s

Comment: Já foi respondido então!

Comment: Semelhantes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89986/pegar-o-id-da-%C3%BAltima-linha-inserida-no-banco-de-dados

Comment: @Edilson, não cara não são semelhantes. Essa primeira nem sabia como pegar o ID. Agora não sei utiliza-lo

Comment: É basicamente a mesma coisa. E outra coisa, é que apesar de teres mostrado qual é problema, ajudava mais se dissesses o que queres realmente, ou o que queres que o script todo faça.

Comment: Desculpa. Não estou habituado com este fórum ainda. :x

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro faça a função retornar o id inserido com com um `return $id`.

```
function saveimagem($name, $image) {

//codigo omitido

   if($result){
      echo "<br/>Foi feito o upload" ;
      $id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
      echo $id;
      return $id;   //<--- linha adicionada
   }else{
      echo "<br/>Não foi feito o upload";
   }
   return false;
}
```

Depois no gravar.php pegue o id de `saveimagem()` com uma atribuição, depois passe a variável no update

gravar.php

```
else {
    $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image = file_get_contents($image);
    $image = base64_encode($image);
    $id_imagem = saveimagem($name, $image); //<--- linha nova atribuição
}
```

Dai lá non update, passe o $id_imagem.

```
where id = $id_imagem");
```

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer com "pegue o ID de `saveimagem()` com uma atribuição. Seria algo como? Não entendo quase nada desse Function. Se puder ajudar nisso '-'

Answer (score 0):

Olha faz o seguinte, vamos deixar seu código mais simples!

Crie um novo arquivo

Pode se chamar conexão

**conexao.php**

```
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
  //Conectar
```

**Inicial.PHP**

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="image" /><br /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="sumit" />
    </form>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['sumit']))
    {
        if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])== FALSE)
        {
            echo "Selecione uma imagem.";
        }
        else
        {
            $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image = file_get_contents($image);
            $image = base64_encode($image);
            include_once 'conexao.php';
            saveimagem($name, $image);
        }
    }

    mostrarimagem();

    function saveimagem($name, $image)
    {
        mysqli_select_db($conexao, "teste");
        $sql = "insert into cadastro (foto)  values ('$image')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        if($result)
        {
            echo "<br/>Foi feito o upload" ;
            $_SESSION['id_temp'] = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
            echo $id;
        }else
        {
            echo "<br/>Não foi feito o upload";
        }
    }

    function mostrarimagem()
    {
        mysqli_select_db($conexao, "teste");
        $sql = "select * from cadastro";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[11].'">';
        }
        mysqli_close($conexao);
    }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Gravar.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//Irá receber os valores enviados e guardar no banco de dados
if($_POST['enviar']){
    include_once 'conexao.php';
    $nome = $_POST['NomeAluno'];
    $dataNasc = $_POST['DataNasc'];
    $sexo = $_POST['Sexo'];
    $numcel = $_POST['Celular'];
    $numtel = $_POST['Telefone'];
    $endereco = $_POST['Endereco'];
    $numres = $_POST['NumResid'];
    $uf = $_POST['UF'];
    $rg = $_POST['RG'];
    $prontuario = $_POST['Prontuario'];
    $datavalidade = $_POST['DataValidade'];
    $curso = $_POST['Curso'];
    $semestre = $_POST['Semestre'];
    $periodo = $_POST['Periodo'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $senha = $_POST['Senha'];

    // Insere os dados no banco
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "UPDATE cadastro set
                                        nome_aluno = '$nome',
                                        data_nascimento = '$dataNasc',
                                        sexo = '$sexo', 
                                        celular = '$numcel',
                                        telefone = '$numtel',
                                        endereco = '$endereco',
                                        numero = '$numres',
                                        uf = '$uf',
                                        rg = '$rg',
                                        prontuario = '$prontuario',
                                        data_validade = '$datavalidade',
                                        curso = '$curso',
                                        semestre = '$semestre',
                                        periodo = '$periodo',
                                        email = '$email',
                                        senha = '$senha'
                                  where id =".$_SESSION['id_temp']);

    // Se os dados forem inseridos com sucesso
    if ($sql){
        echo "Você foi cadastrado com sucesso.";
        if(isset($_SESSION['id_temp'])){
            unset($_SESSION['id_temp']);
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('ocorreu um erro, pois a session para o id não foi criada')</script>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isso eu consegui fazer com `$id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);` , não estou conseguindo fazer o update onde tenha o ultimo ID gravado

Comment: Salva em uma sessão! $_SESSION['id_temp'] = mysqli_insert_id($conexao); - Depois só colocar na query e excluir a session!

Comment: Fiz isso, dai na query coloquei: `where id = 'id_temp'");`, não apareceu nenhum erro mas também não fez o update no banco de dados

Comment: Não brother, você tem que colocar assim: WHERE id = '$_SESSION['id_temp']'"); - Ai depois que você usar faz isso para limpar a sessão, unset($_SESSION['id_temp']);

Comment: Ah sim, fiz a alteração agora deu este erro: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\ifsp\gravar.php on line 45`

Comment: Ve acima e tente novamente!

Comment: Você tirou o include 'inicial.php' mesmo? Coloquei exatamente como me enviou e deu os seguintes erros: `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\ifsp\gravar.php on line 55` e `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\ifsp\gravar.php on line 60`

Comment: Tente agora, caso ter certo tire o else do if(isset($_SESSION['id_temp'])), pois ele serve para dar um alerta caso não esteja gerando o session

Comment: Alterei todos, inclusive a conexão. Porém mesmo assim me retornou um erro:  `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\ifsp\gravar.php on line 40` . No banco de dados sem alterações (update), D:

Comment: Será que não é algo no Banco de dados?

Comment: Voce está usando ajax ou load() do javascript?

Comment: Na onde isso? Único local que usei Javascript foi no formulário para validação de campos, verificar se não está vazio. Já essas "Functions etc" só segui um tutorial na internet de como usa-las

Comment: Putz cara que merda, esqueci do session_start(); - Coloca esse comando no inicio do arquivo inicial e do arquivo gravar!

Comment: Eu tinha pensado nisso até. Coloquei os dois session agora ele mudou o erro para: `Notice: Undefined index: id_temp in C:\wamp\www\ifsp\gravar.php on line 41`.  Tá difícil. Agradeço muito sua paciencia cara

Comment: tentou colocar o session_start só no inicial?

Comment: Sim. dai ele da este erro: `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\ifsp\gravar.php on line 41`  :/