# Inserir ID de uma Tabela em outra Tabela

Tags: php, mysqli

Como eu faço pra inserir o ID de uma tabela em uma outra tabela?

```
<?php
$login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
    if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
      header("Location: index.php");
    }

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lista');
$paginas = $_POST["paginas"];
$ins = "INSERT INTO paginas (paginas, usuario) VALUES ('".$paginas."','".$login_cookie."')";


if(mysqli_query($con, $ins)) {

echo "Registrado com sucesso!";

} else {
    echo "Erro ao registrar!";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Você quer pegar o ID depois do INSERT, correto? Isso deve resolver https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89986/pegar-o-id-da-última-linha-inserida-no-banco-de-dados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue fazer um SELECT e INSERT numa mesma query:

```
INSERT INTO tabela2
SELECT
null,
Id_titulo
FROM tabela1
WHERE Id = '9999'
```

O código acima irá fazer um INSERT na "tabela2" pegando o campo `Id_titulo` da "tabela1" cujo Id é 9999, jogando o dado no segundo campo (assumindo que o primeiro é uma chave primária).

*O código é apenas um exemplo. É preciso adaptá-lo à estrutura das suas tabelas.*

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65118/discussion-on-answer-by-dvdsamm-inserir-id-de-uma-tabela-em-outra-tabela)

Answer (score 2):

Basta criar uma coluna na outra tabela com exatamente o mesmo tipo de dado, ex, se você tem a coluna na primeira tabela sendo INT(11) UNSIGNED, na outra tabela precisa ser exatamente INT(11) UNSIGED.

Só fazendo isso, você já tem a lógica para trabalhar com esses dados, mas se quiser criar o relacionamento fisicamente para utilizar outros recursos como cascata, etc., pode criar uma chave estrangeira (Foreign Key). Porém no MySQL esse recurso só está disponível para a engine InnoDB.

Para ler mais sobre Foreign Key: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi mt bem como por em prática. No caso eu to começando agr a estudar.

Eu estou criando um sistema que armazena total de páginas lidas de livro. O usuário vai no perfil do título e vai ter um input pra ele digitar a página que parou. São 3 tabelas, uma pro usuário, título e páginas, eu consegui inserir o usuário com cookie e as páginas. Mas não estou sabendo como puxar o id do título pra salvar na tabela.